# Calculating NDC Co-ordinates

Tags: opengl, graphics

How does performing the Perspective divide cause the vertex co-ordinates to be NDC (-1 to 1)?

Comment: Hi Edward! Could you edit your question to elaborate a bit on the parts of the vertex transformation pipeline you understand so far, so we know what to focus on in our answers? Showing us how you're constructing your matrices will let us match the conventions of the system you're using, and minimize any confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Perspective division ensures nothing.

Between the Vertex Shader's output and the perspective divide is the [clipping step](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Post-Processing#Clipping). This removes any triangle that's entirely outside of the clip-space region [-W, W], and it actually clips off any parts of a triangle that is outside of that region.

Therefore, after clipping, all triangle vertices lie in the [-W, W] region. So when you divide by W, all vertices will lie in the [-1, 1] region.

Answer (score 0):

The output of the vertex stage is clips space and the visible geometry must be inside [-w, w] after division by w it ends up in [-1, 1].

Any geometry outside the NDC box that will no be draw on screen.

It's the job of the view and perspective matrices to make sure the geometry that you want on screen ends up in that clips space.